# Difficult to identify json data

Tags: android, json

I have json data as mentioned below.

```
{  
"data":[  
  {  
     "Products":{  
        "id":"86",
        "pname":"mi4",
        "pcat":"9",
        "subcat":"8",
        "seccat":"0",
        "oproduct":"1",
        "pdetails":"Good phone",
        "pprice":"10000",
        "pdiscount":"10",
        "qty":"1",
        "qtytype":"GM",
        "dcharge":"40",
        "pimage":null,
        "sname":"Easydeal",
        "sid":"1100",
        "size":"",
        "pincode":""
     }
  }
 ]
}
```

I can identify array as `getJSONArray("datas")`. But I want to get `pname` and `sname` values.

Comment: what is datas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Note: `{ data: [ { Products: {}` is pointless. Your JSON should really only be `[ {"id": 86, "pname": "m14", ... }, ... ]` That is, unless you have more data there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reach the object

```
JSONObject resp=new JSONObject("response");
JSONArray data=resp.getJSONArray("data");
```

now if you want to get object at a particular index(say '0')

```
JSONObject objAt0=data.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject products=objAt0.getJSONObject("products");
String pName=products.getString("pname");
```

you can similarly traverse the array

```
for(int i=0;i<data.lenght();i++){
    JSONObject objAtI=data.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject products=objAtI.getJSONObject("products");
    String pName=products.getString("pname");
}
```

Comment: Close, but you still need to get `"Products"`

Answer (score 1):

To get the to the key "Products" you should do:

```
JSONObject productsObject = YOUROBJECTNAME.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("Products");
```

Then to get the values in productsObject you should do:

```
productsObject.getString("id");
productsObject.getString("pdetails");
```

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following code:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("data");
JSONObject object1 = array.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject products = object1.getJSONObject("Products");
int id = object1.getInt("id");
String pname = object1.getString("pname");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get pname and sname:

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray;
        try {
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            for(int counter = 0; counter <jsonArray.length(); counter++){
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(counter);
                JSONObject products = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("Products");
                String pname = products.getString("pname");
                String sname = products.getString("sname");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**PS:** Poor JSON structure :)